# Failing tests involving async code fail under arbitrary conditions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I've encountered an interesting scenario when doing some testing with `jest` on a new code base I've been working on.

I have looked into the recommendations from jest on how to do [asynchronous testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous), but I feel like they don't account for scenarios where the asynchronous code is triggered from within a method that one calls, hence using the `done` or returning a promise would not work in these scenarios, hence creating a scenarios where some assertions are called before some promises resolve.

In my specific scenario, I made use of [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios) as well, but this is only relevant in the sense that it stubs out the actual work to be done by [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and still returns a promise.

The obvious solution is to allow for a short delay before making the assertions, which works fine. This [readme](https://github.com/moxystudio/redux-mock-store-await-actions) details the problem and solution.

#### Confusing Scenario

The issue though is, if I have understood the problem correctly, I would expect for all tests structured like this to fail without the delay.

However,

- These tests though `pass` when one uses the `then` `catch` pattern to deal with promises inside a function and `fail` when one uses the `async` `await` pattern.
- These tests `pass` when one runs the test individually, and fail when the entire test suite is run- I know :(
- <del>Lastly, these tests pass on some dev's machines and fail on others, which often makes it hard to bring the problem to light</del>
  **UPDATE:**
  This particular one was down to a difference in node versions

#### Question

I am basically wondering what might cause any of the above behaviors and if there's something I am missing since they all seem so arbitrary.

Comment: Without code you are asking us to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: can you add an example of a test that fails? my first assumption is that you need to use the `done` callback to tell the testing framework when the async call is finished and the results meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to race conditions with tests using the same DOM.